# How to get nested properties using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I had been using the line below to grab the value of the `internalIpAddress` property from an ILB App Service Environment in Azure:

```
az resource show `
  --ids "/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourceGroups/$ilbase_rg_name/providers/Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/$ilbase_name/capacities/virtualip" `
  --query "internalIpAddress"
```

The format of the `virtualip` resource was:

```
{
  "internalIpAddress": "10.30.0.139",
  "outboundIpAddresses": [
    "13.72.76.135"
  ],
  "serviceIpAddress": "13.72.76.135",
  "vipMappings": []
}
```

Seems like in the past day or so, the format of the `virtualip` resource has now changed to this:

```
{
  "additionalProperties": {
    "internalIpAddress": "10.30.0.139",
    "outboundIpAddresses": [
      "13.72.76.135"
    ],
    "serviceIpAddress": "13.72.76.135",
    "vipMappings": []
  },
  "id": null,
  "identity": null,
  "kind": null,
  "location": null,
  "managedBy": null,
  "name": null,
  "plan": null,
  "properties": null,
  "sku": null,
  "tags": null,
  "type": null
}
```

And now my command no longer works...it returns nothing. I can modify my command to get the entire `additionalProperties` object but I then don't know how to parse thru it to get just the value of the `internalIpAddress` property.

Another interesting note on this is, if you go to the Azure Resource Explorer and navigate to the `virtualip` resource, it still shows it in the same old format. If you try the PowerShell code the Azure Resource Explorer gives you to query the resource, it returns nothing.

Here is the PowerShell the Azure Resource Explorer said to use:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName MyRG -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments/capacities -ResourceName "myilbase/virtualip" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01
```

Looking for some help on how to parse the nested `internalIpAddress` property from the `additionalProperties` object

Comment: Where do you find the "additionalProperties"? I do not find it in the ASE. It also shows as before.

Comment: @CharlesXu if you run the `az resource show` command I have at the top of this post...it should display the `additionalProperties` output format. It did for me.

Comment: @CharlesXu the most bizarre thing...when I went back this morning and ran the same exact code...it is now back to working like it has in the past and now I am not seeing (or able to query) and `additionalProperties` object. I swear...I was not under the influence yesterday when I was seeing this :)

Comment: @CharlesXu discovered this morning that I was experiencing the issue with `additionalProperties` on my workstation because it had an outdated version of AZ CLI. I find this odd because I originally wrote this code on that workstation and now it is behaving differently than my laptop which has a newer version of the AZ CLI tools. Updated workstation and now they behave the same way.

Comment: Does just the older CLI version cause the issue? The output of the CLI just show the properties defined by Azure, it also shows in the Azure Template. I did not see it.

Comment: @CharlesXu yes, just the older version. Yesterday while on laptop, query was working as expected. This morning on workstation, query was returning null unless I queried for `additionalProperties`. I upgraded AZ CLI version on workstation and then query was working fine.

Comment: Which CLI version does it happen?

Comment: @CharlesXu I can't remember exactly but it was version something like 2.0.32 and now I have upgraded to 2.0.55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just traverse the object like you normally would:

```
--query "additionalProperties.internalIpAddress"
```